# как можно изменить текст ошибки invalidcastexception при валидации поля

Tags: c#, валидация, преобразование, avalonia

Когда у меня textbox пустой или есть буквы, то возникает ошибка InvalidCastException: " is not a valid number. Как можно изменить текст этой ошибки, какой атрибут валидации применить или как переопределить. Ошибка возникает для свойства типа decimal. Вот пример свойства:

```
[Range(1, 500000.00, ErrorMessage = "Неприемлемая цена")]
[Required]
public decimal Price { get; set; }
```

textbox привязан к этому свойству

```
private Product _editingProduct;
    public Product EditingProduct
    {
        get => _editingProduct;
        set => this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref _editingProduct, value);
    }
```

Вот так в разметке: `Text="{Binding EditingProduct.Price}"`
Использую Avalonia (0.10.18)

Comment: [Валидация WPF](https://metanit.com/sharp/wpf/14.php)